# Products not appearing under admin grid

Tags: magento2.2

I imported products via API calls successfully. After sync, products not appearing under admin->grid... I can see under table "catalog_product_entity".

I flushed cache, reindex and run cron manually.

Still getting the same issue.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Seems Magento-2 bug.

Please sort the product grid via "ID". It must work.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you open an issue on the github project for this?

Comment: Please do it, so the bug can be found and fixed and other devs looking for info like me can find them more easily.